# Как ввести целочисленное значение в переменную в Tkinter, Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, типы-данных

Пишу небольшой калькулятор на Python, используя модуль Tkinter для GUI. Столкнулся с проблемой: я не могу ввести именно целочисленное значение в переменную. При попытке сложить два введенных числа, выдает ошибку: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'StringVar' and 'StringVar'`. Пробовал так же использовать `IntVar` - ошибка та же: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntVar' and 'IntVar'`. Хотелось бы узнать, как вводить целочисленные значения в переменные и выполнять с ними арифметические действия.

Код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Calculator Pro')
root.geometry("300x300")

def sum():
    print (number1 + number2)

number1 = StringVar()
number2 = StringVar()

number1_entry = Entry(textvariable=number1)
number1_entry.pack()
number2_entry = Entry(textvariable=number2)
number2_entry.pack()
bt = Button(text="Summa", command=sum)
bt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Скриншот (так, на всякий случай):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте переменные IntVar и получите значения перед суммированием

```
def sum():
    print (number1.get() + number2.get())

number1 = IntVar()
number2 = IntVar()
```

либо переопределите класс

```
class myIntVar(IntVar) :
    def __add__(self, other) :
        return self.get()+other.get()

def sum():
    print (number1 + number2)

number1 = myIntVar()
number2 = myIntVar()
```