# Tkinter виджет Entry, преобразование в int

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем привет. Пишу калькулятор, логика в консоли вся работает, но при работе с библиотекой я натыкаюсь на ошибки. Пожалуйста, помогите понять и исправить

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
message = StringVar()
input = Entry(window, textvariable = message)
input.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
result = 0
n = 0
numbs = [0, 0]
loop = True
def vvod(n, numbs):
    a = int(message.get())
    numbs[n] = a
    n =+ 1
    return(n, numbs)
btnok = Button(window, Text = "Ввод", command = vvod(n, numbs))
btnok.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

def summury (loop, result, n, numbs):
    while(loop):
        vvod(n, numbs)
        loop = False
    result = sum(numbs)
    n = 0
    numbs = [0, result]
    return(result, n, numbs)
abtnplus = Label(window, Text = "+", command = summury(loop, result, n, numbs))
abtnplus.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

def minus (loop, result, n, numbs):
    while(loop):
        vvod(n, numbs)
        loop = False
    result = sum(numbs)
    n = 0
    numbs = [0, result]
    return(result, n, numbs)
abtnplus = Label(window, Text = "+", command = summury(loop, result, n, numbs))
abtnplus.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

def result(result):
    resultlable = Label(window, Text = result)
    resultlable.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/1111/main.py", line 16, in <module>
   btnok = Button(window, Text = "Ввод", command = vvod(n, numbs))
   File "D:/1111/main.py", line 12, in vvod
   a = int(message.get())
   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Посмотрите это: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112023/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-tkinter-python)

Comment: А что если в `message.get()` у вас пустая строка?

Answer (score 1):

Тут не происходит привязка функции на нажатие кнопки, а происходит сразу вызов функции `vvod`, в итоге функция вызывается когда в полях ввода еще пусто:

```
btnok = Button(window, Text = "Ввод", command = vvod(n, numbs))
```

Чтобы функция вызывалась в момент нажатия на кнопку, нужно завернуть в лямбду:

```
btnok = Button(window, text = "Ввод", command = lambda: vvod(n, numbs))
```

Также обратите внимание, что регистр в имен переменных (параметров в данном случае) имеет значение: должно быть `text`, а не `Text`.

Если функции не нужны никакие дополнительные параметры, то можно в command предавать просто функцию без скобок, но если вы добавляете скобки - то это уже будет вызовом функции, а не ссылкой на функцию.

Также, в таких строках:

```
abtnplus = Label(window, text = "+", command = summury(loop, result, n, numbs))
```

у `Label` нет параметра `command` (т.к. это не кнопка), поэтому будет на это ругаться.

Если нужна реакция на клик по `Label`, нужно использовать `bind`:

```
abtnplus = Label(window, text = "+")
abtnplus.bind('<1>', lambda event: summury(loop, result, n, numbs))
```

Comment: не помогло, но изменились ошибки

Comment: @Ivan, я должен угадать что за ошибки?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/1111/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    btnok = Button(window, Text = "Ввод", command = lambda: vvod)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2369, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-Text"

Comment: @Ivan дополнил ответ

Comment: @Ivan, разобрались?